# Retrieving executed query list in BigQuery via SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a table similar to v$sql in Oracle where I can retrieve data associated with a particular query that was run in BigQuery using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a table similar to v$sql in oracle where I can retrieve data associated with a particular query that was run in BigQuery using SQL?

Yes, In BigQuery it's called Jobs and you have few ways to retrieve it:

1. Via the UI from the menu on the left-hand side, Query History

[image]

2. Via API by calling the [Jobs API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list)
3. Via BigQuery `bq` [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls) using the `show` option as follow

   bq --location=[LOCATION] show -j [JOB_ID]